How to Display a Selected Part of a YouTube Video or any video with url Stream in React?
I'm developing a React app where I'm streaming YouTube videos using a custom video player component. However, I want to enhance the user experience by displaying only a selected part of the video stream. Essentially, I want to hide the video player controls and restrict the visible portion of the video to a specific segment.How can i achive that? Thanks in advance!
Here's my current implementation of the video stream component:
     import React from 'react';
   import styled from 'styled-components';

 const VideoWrapper = styled.div`
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 `;

const VideoPlayer = styled.iframe`
   width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #76b900;
 border-radius: 8px;
   `;

  const VideoStream = () => {
 const videoLink = process.env.REACT_APP_VIDEO_LINK;
 const videoId = getYouTubeVideoId(videoLink);
 const embedUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;

  return (
  <VideoWrapper>
  <VideoPlayer src={embedUrl} allowFullScreen />
</VideoWrapper>
  );
 };

   function getYouTubeVideoId(url) {
  // Regular expression to extract the video ID from YouTube URL
  const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^/]+\/.+\/| 
 (?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/;
 const match = url.match(regex);
  if (match && match[1]) {
  return match[1];
 } else {
  throw new Error('Invalid YouTube URL');
 }
 }

 export default VideoStream;


I've done something very similiar before, You can use Youtube player api.
You should just be able to Swap out your code for this:
 import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    const VideoStream = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef(null);
    const videoLink = process.env.REACT_APP_VIDEO_LINK;
    const videoId = getYouTubeVideoId(videoLink);
    useEffect(() => {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = initializePlayer;

    return () => {
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = null;
    };
     }, []);
     const initializePlayer = () => {
    new window.YT.Player(videoRef.current, {
      videoId: videoId,
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 0, 
        start: 30, 
        end: 90, 
      },
    });
    };
     return <div ref={videoRef}></div>;
    };
    function getYouTubeVideoId(url) {
    const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^/]+\/.+\/| 
     (?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/;
     const match = url.match(regex);
     if (match && match[1]) {
      return match[1];
      } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid YouTube URL');
     }
     }
    export default VideoStream;

Then you see inside the const initializePlayer section, you have a start and end, this clarifies the seconds you want the video to start from and end at.

what if i have different url other than youtube.i have multiples vieo sources to provide video
